# How to add javafx environment variable in Ubuntu now that the Oracle removed javafx from JDK?

Tags: javafx, environment-variables, java-11

I recently started learning javafx but now I came to know it was removed from the core JDK since java 11. I can't seem to find a way to compile javafx application. The import declaration is not working (I am using MVC design pattern). Is there a way to get around this?
[I am using VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw1Fj.png)

Comment: Do you know this Web site? https://openjfx.io/

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Java 9, JavaFX was moved out of the JDK so that updates to JavaFX did not have to wait on the next JDK release (at least that's what I remember).  When Ubuntu switched to JDK 11 from JDK 8, they added a new package "openjfx" that provides the JavaFX libraries.

So you have a couple of options to use JavaFX.

**Install OpenJFX**

```
sudo apt install openjfx libopenjfx-java
```

**Setup Gradle Build**

If you are using gradle to build, you can set it up to download whatever JavaFX version you want.  Follow the instructions from [openjfx](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle) for setting up a basic gradle configuration.  The linked page has an example file you can start with.

You may also want to consider using Intellij Idea Community edition IDE instead of VS Code. I think VS Code is excellent and have used it for a couple of years now including for JavaFX development.  I recently switched to Intellij and the features it provides for java development are step above VS Code.  Plus it's provided as a snap so easy to install:

```
snap install intellij-idea-community --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

So, about the environment variable. I'm guessing you are on Linux, so you have two ways of setting it:

A) set it for current session;

B) set it globally.

Option A: open the Terminal and execute `export PATH_TO_FX=[absolute path to Javafx folder]/lib`. This will create a variable for your current user for the current session only - you will have to execute it every time you boot your OS.

Option B: locate the file `/etc/profile`; then back it up; then open it for editing and add the `export PATH_TO_FX="[absolute path to Javafx folder]/lib"` line to the end of it. Save the file and restart your system. This way the variable will be preserved for all users permanently.

Finally, test the Javafx presence by launching your application jar - `java -jar --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml your.jar` (or launch your main class as shown in the documentation).